# ChartJS - Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart Tooltip being cut off by Bottom of Canvas

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to add multiple lines in the tooltip for my horizontal stacked bar chart but the last couple lines are getting cut off by the end of the chart canvas. Is it possible to make the tooltip extend over the end of the chart canvas?

[image]

```
tooltips: {
 mode: 'nearest',
 intersect: true,
   callbacks: {
     footer: function() {
      var withBreaks = "Hello World. \n My name is Jennifer. \n What is your name?"
       return withBreaks;
     },
  }
},
```

Answer (score 6):

Either you can add bottom padding to your canvas

```
options: {
layout: {
  padding: {
     bottom: 25  //set that fits the best
  }
 },
}
```

Another option is to set the yAlign of tooltip to center, so the tooltip won't occupy the bottom space of the canvas.

```
options: {
 tooltips: {
    yAlign: 'center'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/622) issue, especially https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/622#issuecomment-72480781 comment.

A similar problem was faced here too.